# Google Maps in React-Native (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native

My goal is to display a Google Map in React Native. I have seen examples that use the Google Maps SDK with an UIMapView or a MapBox map, but that is not what I am looking for.

I currently have no errors. Here is my code:

index.ios.js

```
'use strict';
import React, {
    AppRegistry,
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import GoogleMaps from './ios/GoogleMaps.js';

class RCTGoogleMaps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <GoogleMaps style={styles.map}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    map: {
        height: 500,
        width: 300,
        marginLeft: 50
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RCTGoogleMaps', () => RCTGoogleMaps);
```

ios/GoogleMaps.js

```
var {requireNativeComponent} = require('react-native');
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTGoogleMapViewManager', null);
```

ios/RCTGoogleMapViewManager.h

```
#ifndef RCTGoogleMapViewManager_h
#define RCTGoogleMapViewManager_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RCTGoogleMapViewManager : RCTViewManager<UITextViewDelegate>
@end

#endif /* RCTGoogleMapViewManager_h */
```

ios/GoogleMapViewManager.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTGoogleMapViewManager.h"
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "UIView+React.h"
@import GoogleMaps;

@implementation RCTGoogleMapViewManager
  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view {
  GMSMapView *mapView_;
  // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
  // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                          longitude:151.20
                                                               zoom:6];
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  UIView *newView_ = mapView_;
  //self.view = mapView_;

  // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
  marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
  marker.title = @"Sydney";
  marker.snippet = @"Australia";
  marker.map = mapView_;
  return newView_;
}

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(text, NSString)

@end
```

There is a red border around the  component, but nothing displays inside. I am new to React Native and new to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, they will not let me upload a screenshot until I have more reputation.

There is one line I suspect to be off, but have no idea what to change it to. Line #8 in RCTGoogleMapViewManager.h says, "@interface RCTGoogleMapViewManager : RCTViewManager". I have used UITextViewDelegates for other custom components, but this map is not a TextView. That might be it, but I have no clue.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a red border around the component but nothing displays inside, that means you have no correctly linked a library.

Check out the docs here:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.25/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out https://github.com/peterprokop/ReactNativeGoogleMaps? It looks fairly preliminary but it should still be pretty useful to you.